# C# Get exact string formation from 'double' type

Tags: c#, string

As I'm working on C#, I have one field named 'Amount'.

```
double amount = 10.0;
```

So, I want the result like `'10.0'` after converting it to string.

If my value

`amount = 10.00`, then I want result `'10.00'` after converting it to string.

So, Basically I want exact result in string as it is in double type. (With precisions).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is not possible. A `double` in C# is a simple 64-bit floating-point value. It doesn't store precision. You can print your value with one decimal places, or two, as other answers describe, but not in a way that's "preserves" the variable's original precision.

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = string.Format( "{0:f2}", amount );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string amountString = amount.ToString("N2");
```

"N2" is the format string used as the first parameter to the .ToString() method.

"N" stands for number, and 2 stands for the number of decimal places.

More on string format's here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As [@Michael Petratta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641023/c-get-exact-string-formation-from-double-type/3641033#3641033) points out, `double` doesn't carry with it the precision of the input. If you need that information, you will  need to store it yourself. Then you could reconstuct the input string doing something like:

```
static public string GetPrecisionString( double doubleValue, int precision)
{
    string FormattingString = "{0:f" + precision + "}";
    return string.Format( FormattingString, doubleValue);
}
```